# Django nested model rest frame wrok

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Models.py

```
class Persion (models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    age = models.IntegerField()

class Address(models.Model):
    city = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    state = models.TextField(max_length=300)
```

Serializer.py:

```
class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields ='__all__'

class PersionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    address = AddressSerializer( required= True)
    class Meta:
        model = Persion
        fields = ['name', 'age' , 'address']
```

**Error Message:**

Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `address` on serializer `PersionSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Persion` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Persion' object has no attribute 'address'.

**What am i missing?**

- Anything needed to be added in settings page ( i added rest_framework)
- Anything in urls page?

I need output like this

```
[
     { name:"nikhil",
       age: 24,
       address:{
                 city:"coimbatore",
                }
     }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class PersionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Persion 
    fields = (
        "name",
        "age",  
    )
    

def to_representation(self, instance):
    data = super().to_representation(instance)
    data['address] = AddressSerializer(Address.objects.all(),many=True).data
    
    return data
```

This is also a way if you want to send all the address
and if you want to filter according to the person model using a foreign key which you do not have right now you can do in this way assuming person_id in the address model.

```
class PersionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Persion 
    fields = (
        "name",
        "age",  
    )
    

def to_representation(self, instance):
    data = super().to_representation(instance)
    data['address] = AddressSerializer(Address.objects.filter(person_id=data["id"]),many=True).data
    
    return data
```

hope it would help :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `PersionSerializer`'s `address` add `many=True` like so:

```py
class PersionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    address = AddressSerializer( required= True, many=True )
    class Meta:
        model = Persion
        fields = ['name', 'age' , 'address']
```

Since you are returning a list of objects. Check out the docs [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/).

Answer (score 0):

Persion model has no attribute address.
You might be doing

```
persion = Persion.objects.first()
persion_serialized = PersionSerializer(persion).data
```

or

```
persion = Persion.objects.all()
persion_serialized = PersionSerializer(persion, many=True).data
```

Now the problem is Persion model object has no attribute address.

Actually for your intended result your Persion model should be like:

```
class Address(models.Model):
   city = models.TextField(max_length=300)
   state = models.TextField(max_length=300)

class Persion (models.Model):
   name = models.TextField(max_length=300)
   age = models.IntegerField()
   address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

Also I think your PersionSerializer should be like:

```
class PersionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   address = AddressSerializer(read_only=True)
   class Meta:
      model = Persion
      fields = ['name', 'age' , 'address']
```

only then your you will get the data as intended.